Managed Identity for Cosmos DB: "Local Authorization is disabled. Use an AAD token to authorize all requests"
I am trying to disable local authentication for my Cosmos DB and use Managed Identity for my Web App and Function App which connects to it. I have granted both apps the Cosmos DB Built-in Contributor role and verified they are assigned via az cli. However, I am getting the error:
"The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as the computed signature. Server used following string to sign - . Learn more: https:\/\/aka.ms\/cosmosdb-tsg-mac-signature","Local Authorization is disabled. Use an AAD token to authorize all requests."

This is the updated Cosmos Client:
var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(_endpointUrl, new DefaultAzureCredential(), options);

I have followed this guide to disable local auth
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#disable-local-auth
Is the Cosmos DB Built in Contributor Role enough?

Perhaps DefaultAzureCredential picks up the wrong credentials? are you running locally? I did a blog post about DefaultAzureCredential  here https://nestenius.se/2024/04/18/default-azure-credentials-under-the-hood/

Not running locally, also tried using ManagedIdentityCredential

User assigned or system assigned Identity? I would also validate that the identity works with some other system, like blog storage.

System assigned for both Function app and Web app. We are currently using the Function Apps Managed Identity for storage account as it is using a Blob Trigger, and it works fine. The answer below suggests to verify client options, are there any specific ones that need to be set? Currently connection mode is default which is direct.

Perhaps the Built in Contributor role is not enough permissions? Are there any other role assignments I should try adding?

Fixed - missed a Cosmos Client init which was still using key auth.
